# Writing out a struct with integers and strings in binary mode

Tags: c, printf

I have been stuck on this for several hours and I'm unsure what to do
and I am unsure how to implement an Add file i/o to my program any help and or assistance would be appreciated I've already tried a bunch of stuff but I am very confused.

Here is the text of the assignment:

> **Add file i/o to your program**
>
> Implement a function `writeEmpToFile` that takes two arguments: a `struct Employee` pointer and a `FILE *`.
>
> It should write each field in order as an appropriate type. Note that you will probably want to write a length of the name before you write the characters of the name.  By doing this, when you write the load function below, you can read the length of the string and use it to malloc a buffer of the proper size to hold the name.
>
> Because of the embedded name pointer, you CAN NOT write the `Employee struct` as a single struct. You will need to write it out field by field.  You will want to write this as a binary file, not as a text file.
>
> Implement a SAVE command in your main loop that will save all the employees out to a file. The SAVE command should ask for a file name, similar to the way your FIND command asked for a name.
>
> Implement a function `readEmpFromFile` that takes a `FILE *` as the only argument and returns a pointer to a struct employee. This function should read the information from the file (reversing what writeEmpToFile does), create a new employee and fill in the data. If the FILE has no more info (is at end of file), this function should return NULL. This function must also ensure any employee actually created (not the NULL) is added to the array (as is done in createEmployee).
>
> Change main to load employees from a file if a command line argument is given to the program (using your `readEmpFromFile` function you just wrote).

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EMPS_SIZE 20
#define SSN_SIZE 9
#define MAX_EMPS 19

typedef struct {
    int salary;
    int yearBorn;
    char ssn[SSN_SIZE];
    char *name;
} Employee;

Employee *emps[EMPS_SIZE];

int totalEmps = 0;

void displayEmployee(Employee *person) {
    printf("\nYou entered the name: %s\nYou entered the year: %d\nYou entered the social security number: ",
           person->name, person->yearBorn);

    for (int i = 0; i < SSN_SIZE; i++) {
        if (i == 2) {
            printf("%c-", person->ssn[i]);
        } else
        if (i == 4) {
            printf("%c-", person->ssn[i]);
        } else
        if (i == 9) {
            printf("%c ", person->ssn[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%c", person->ssn[i]);
        }
    }

    int num = person->salary / 1000;
    int num2 = person->salary % 1000;
    printf("\nYou entered the salary: $%d,%03d\n\n\n", num, num2);

}

void readEmployee(Employee *person) {

    int *inputYearBorn = &person->yearBorn;
    int *inputSalary = &person->salary;
    char buff[256];

    printf("Welcome to the add employee manager!\n\n");
    printf("Enter the Employees name: ");
    scanf("%s", buff);

    person->name = malloc(strlen(buff + 1));
    strcpy(person->name, buff);
    printf("Enter the year the Employee was born: ");
    scanf("%d", inputYearBorn);
    printf("Enter the salary the Employee makes: ");
    scanf("%d", inputSalary);
    printf("Enter the ssn of the Employee: ");
    scanf("%s", buff);

    *person->ssn = '\0';

    strncat(person->ssn, buff, 9);
}

void createEmployee(void) {
    if (totalEmps <= MAX_EMPS) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_EMPS; ++i) {
            if (emps[i] == NULL) {
                Employee *newEmployee = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
                emps[i] = newEmployee;
                totalEmps++;
                readEmployee(newEmployee);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("You cannot hire anymore employees\n\n");
    }
}

void releaseEmployee(Employee *person) {
    free(person->name);
    free(person);
}

void listEmployees(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_EMPS; i++) {
        if (emps[i] == NULL) {
            printf("No employee at : %d\n", i);
        } else {
            printf("Employee position in list : %d\n", i);
            displayEmployee(emps[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("employees!\n\n");
}

Employee *findEmployee(char *name) {

    printf("You entered the name: %s\n\n", name);
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalEmps; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(emps[i]->name, name)) {
            printf("%s is an employee! They are at: %d\n", name, i);
            return emps[i];
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("doesn't exist\n");
    return NULL;
}

void fireEmployee(char *name) {

    printf("You entered the name: %s\n\n", name);

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalEmps; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(emps[i]->name, name)) {
            printf("%s is now fired! They were at: %d\n", name, i);
            free(emps[i]);
            emps[0] = NULL;
            return;
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("employee doesn't exist\n");
    return;
}

int salaryComp(Employee **a, Employee **b) {

    Employee *empA = *a;
    Employee *empB = *b;

    if (&empA->salary == NULL && &empB->salary != NULL) {
        printf("I got here 2\n\n");
        return 1;
    } else
    if (&empB->salary == NULL && &empA->salary != NULL) {
        printf("I got here 3\n\n");
        return -1;
    } else
    if (&empA->salary == NULL && &empB->salary == NULL) {
        printf("I got here 4\n\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("empA salary == %d\n", empA->salary);
        printf("empB salary == %d\n", empB->salary);
        return (empB->salary - empA->salary);
    }
}

int nameComp(Employee **a, Employee **b) {

    Employee *empA = *a;
    Employee *empB = *b;

    if (empA == NULL && empB != NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else
    if (empB == NULL && empA != NULL) {
        return -1;
    } else
    if (empA == NULL && empB == NULL) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void sort(Employee *base[], int n, int (*compareFunc)(Employee **, Employee **)) {

    qsort((void **)base, n, sizeof(void *),
          (int (*)(const void *, const void *))compareFunc);
}

void main(void) {

    int end = 1;
    char *command;
    char buff[256];
    char *findEmp;
    char findBuff[256];
    char *sortType;
    char sortBuff[256];
    char hire[] = "HIRE";
    char list[] = "LIST";
    char quit[] = "QUIT";
    char find[] = "FIND";
    char fire[] = "FIRE";
    char _sort[] = "SORT";
    char salary[] = "SALARY";
    char name[] = "NAME";

    printf("Employee Manager\n");

    while (end) {
        printf("Would you like to HIRE, LIST, FIND, FIRE, SORT, or QUIT?\n\n");
        scanf("%s", buff);

        command = malloc(strlen(buff + 1));
        strcpy(command, buff);
        printf("command: %s\n\n", command);

        if (!strcmp(command, hire)) {
            createEmployee();
        } else
        if (!strcmp(command, list)) {
            listEmployees();
        } else
        if (!strcmp(command, find)) {
            printf("Enter an employee name, to find:\n\n");
            scanf("%s", findBuff);
            findEmp = malloc(strlen(findBuff + 1));
            strcpy(findEmp, findBuff);
            findEmployee(findEmp);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(command, fire)) {
            printf("employee name to fire\n\n");
            scanf("%s", findBuff);
            findEmp = malloc(strlen(findBuff + 1));
            strcpy(findEmp, findBuff);
            fireEmployee(findEmp);
        } else
        if (!strcmp(command, _sort)) {
            printf("sort by SALARY or NAME?\n\n");
            scanf("%s", sortBuff);
            sortType = malloc(strlen(sortBuff + 1));
            strcpy(sortType, sortBuff);
            if (!strcmp(sortType, name)) {
                printf("by name\n\n");
                sort(emps, EMPS_SIZE, nameComp);
                listEmployees();
            } else
            if (!strcmp(sortType, salary)) {
                printf("by salary\n\n");
                sort(emps, EMPS_SIZE, salaryComp);
                listEmployees();
            } else {
                printf("Improper sort type entered, exiting to main menu\n\n");
            }
        } else
        if (!strcmp(command, quit)) {
            printf("Quitting\n\n");
            end = 0;
        } else {
            printf("enter a proper command\n\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework questions are fine on Stack Overflow, but you should keep in mind that some schools may consider posting the entire question to be cheating and it can be difficult or impossible to delete questions that have received an answer. It is almost always preferable to pick out and post only the code that is directly relevant to your question. If you want to learn more you can read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: thank you very much for letting me know I'm new to this site

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the code with warnings enabled gives multiple occurrences of this warning:

```
220321-employees.c:143:16: warning: comparison of address of 'empA->salary' equal to a null pointer is always false
      [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (&empA->salary == NULL && &empB->salary != NULL) {
         ~~~~~~^~~~~~    ~~~~
```

`&empA->salary` is the address of a field of the structure pointed to by `empA`, it cannot be `NULL`. It makes no sense to take the address for this test, you probably want to move all null `Employee` pointers to the end of the array so you should write:

```
int salaryComp(Employee **a, Employee **b) {
    Employee *empA = *a;
    Employee *empB = *b;

    if (empA == NULL || empB == NULL) {
        /* compare null pointers as greater than non null pointers */
        return empA ? -1 : empB ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        /* sort by decreasing salary */
        return (empA->salary < empB->salary) - (empA->salary > empB->salary);
    }
}

int nameComp(Employee **a, Employee **b) {

    Employee *empA = *a;
    Employee *empB = *b;

    if (empA == NULL || empB == NULL) {
        /* compare null pointers as greater than non null pointers */
        return empA ? -1 : empB ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        /* sort by name, ignoring case */
        return strcasecmp(empA->name, empB->name);
    }
}
```